# Trying to make a Button that will reset all other buttons background colors

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 100 buttons in a 10x10 square, They change color when clicked.

```
        private void alternateColor(Control ctrl)
    {
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "LightGray":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                break;
            default:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                break;
        }
    }
    private void matrixButtonClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        alternateColor(sender as Control);              
    }
```

What I want a button that resets every button that has been changed to lightblue to lightgray. Any help would be appreciated

```
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ????
    }
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Finding the buttons?

Comment: By the way, why are you checking `ctrl.BackColor.Name` when you can just check `ctrl.BackColor`. That is `case Color.LightGray:` ...

Comment: BTW, you could write `alternateColor` like this: `private void alternateColor(Control ctrl) { ctrl.BackColor = ctrl.BackColor == Color.LightGray ? Color.LightBlue : Color.LightGray; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq to filter the buttons with specific back color. You can use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get controls of button type and use [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to filter buttons with BackColor name equal to LightBlue

```
//Get the button in form with LightBlue back color.
var formLightBlueButton = form1.Controls.OfType<Button>()
                         .Where(b=>b.BackColor == Color.LightBlue);

//Changing the color of buttons
foreach(var button in formLightBlueButton)
      button.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
```

**Edit** **Using foreach loop to get and set the button properties instead of using LINQ seem more appropriate** here. Simply use `is` operator to filter button and change the back color.

```
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
   if (ctrl is Button && ctrl.BackColor == Color.Maroon)
       ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
```

Comment: you don't really need to filter the buttons - they will get all the same color anyway - just saying

Comment: Just to ensure that it should not get buttons not satisfying the condition i.e Color.LightBlue

Answer (score 0):

I could think of several approaches:

1. iterate through the children in the conatainer, pick each button and set it's color back
2. use a event/IObservable you subscribe for each button on creation and that notifies the buttons of the changed color
3. improve on 2 by using a viewmodel (MVVM)

The list is sorted by difficulty but the later ones give you better design and depending on your problem I would advise at least 2

PS: I cannot give you meaningful code without having a bit of a clue what you are really doing there - if I can see more of your code/definitions I will add some.